# Authentication patterns in microservices

Tags: spring, spring-security, jwt, microservices, system-design

There are several approaches for managing authentication in microservices including service to service authentication. I want to understand which approach is better.

1. When a user logs in to the system auth-service call is happening and the auth-service returns an opaque token (not JWT), then each API call contains that opaque token Gateway validates the token through the auth-service generates a new JWT token for downstream services. So downstream services will not have to call auth-service each time to validate the token.
2. From the beginning auth-service will generate a JWT token.

   2.1. Gateway will validate and pass it through downstream services and all services will use the same token

   2.2. Gateway validates and generates a new token each time, and also downstream services do the same.

Each approach has its pros and cons.

Questions:

Approach 1. Gateway each time needs to doo auth-service call to validate?

Approach  2. What will be the expiration time for JWT tokens? Who needs to handle the expirations, what token expires in between who needs to regenerate it again? JWT tokens must be short-lived, so whether it will not affect client behavior, or refresh tokens should come in the picture here.

So I am confused about which approach is good,or are there other approaches.Please advise me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JWTs should be avoided to be exposed to the outside world since these could potentially include sensitive information in custom claims. Especially if you work in a large company, where you can't keep track of what ends up in different claims.

So if using opague tokens (which you should) the gateway should verify and exchange the token to a JWT that can be used internally inside your network.

All services `SHOULD` always be setup with `zero trust` in mind.

All services should if possible fetch JWKs to verify the incoming JWTs. And these JWKs should be rotated on a regular basis.

This is to avoid that if a malicious actor gets access to the internal network he shouldnt be able to do any request to any service just because he has passed the gateway.

When it comes to expiration times, these should be set by the issuer and should be kept short because one of the big problems is that its easy to issue a token, but harder to revoke one.

The flow is usually as such:

- Client logs in and gets issued a AT (access token) and a RT (refresh token)
- Client presents opague AT token to a service in the backend
- Gateway exchanges the opague token for a JWT
- Gateway passes the JWT to the service that is requested
- The resource server validates the JWT
- if request is denied a httpstatus of 401 is returned to the calling client
- the client receives the 401 and then presents its refresh to the issuer that will issue a new AT token.
- request is redone with the new AT token.

Comment: This makes sense to me, but one question each downstream service should generate its own JWT token? Meaning Gateway generates and calls service A, service A validates and needs to generate a new one or the same token to pass through? 
If each service needs to pass through the same token generated by JWT, who needs to take care of JWTs expiration ?

Comment: You have an authorization server issuing the tokens, keycloak, okta, auth0, curity, spring authorization server. Read the oauth2 specification. Each service verifies the signature and then reads the tokens expiration claim and rejects the token if it is expired. If token is rejected you return a 401 out to the calling client, client tries to refresh

Comment: In my answer it says ”gateway exchanges the token for a jwt” so the gateway calls the issuer and presents a opague token and gets JWT back. So no, each service does not generate a token. The issuer creates tokens. Read the oauth2 specc, please read it

Comment: I see, so all downstream services use the same JWT token, and if it expires in between what will happen? For example, Gateway passes to A, A to B, B to C, and in C it expires. Should B refresh it?  Because the token from beginning was correct .
By saying `Gateway exchanges the opague token for a JWT` you mean to get JWT corresponding to opaque , some transformation ?

Comment: Im going to stop you know, you are continuing to ask questions in comments which is not allowed. Stack overflow is not a forum. I answered your question and you should really read the oauth spec. Good luck